# rsnapshot doesn't backup new folders

Tags: linux, backup, nfs, nextcloud, rsnapshot

I am facing a weird behavior with rsnapshot. I am using it on a dedicated backup server to backup several machines. One of them is nextcloud.

The data folder is mounted to the nextcloud VM under `/data/` per nfs from the Host machine. At the first run the `.sync` folder was created and all backups went well. A new user came a long and logged in for the first time in to nextcloud, so his directory was created under `/data/`.

This directory is not being backed up, rsnapshot just creates the links and rotates! And I am wondering why? Does it have something to do with `sync_first` option, or with the fact that I am backing up the share on the nextcloud VM and not from the host?

I am backing up the whole `/data/` folder.

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you use rsnapshot using the `first_sync` option set, you always have to run `rsnapshot sync` before running e.g. `rsnapshot daily`.  The sync command will actually download the files, the other commands will just rotate. Are you using the sync command?

Comment: Hi, I just figured that out after posting the question. Indeed in my `/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot` file I didn't have the sync run configured, so I added it and started the Backup from scratch. It looks good now, I wanted to wait until the next run today and confirm the solution. Thanks a lot for the answer.